# How do we derive our loss function from the gradient objective?

Tags: machine-learning, math, vector, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been dwelling through RL theory and practice and one particular part I find hard to properly understand is the relation between the practical `loss` function and the theoretical objective/gradient of the objective. How do we derive one from another? Maybe it is easier with an example:

#### **Reinforce with baseline:**

**Theoretical Critic Objective Gradient**

[image]

**Practical loss (pseudocode) I've come across:**

```py
critic_loss = 0.5 * (returns - v_hat(states))**2
```

**Where is this coming from?** **Is it the negative inverse of the gradient of `∇J(w)`**? If so, could somebody show how it's done? I can only find resources on how to do this for w with fixed dimensions.

I might be completely off here, not getting some foundational property. If that is the case, I would thank deeply if you could direct me to relevant (introductory) literature.

Comment: Interesting question, however it's off topic here. Try stats.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The typical path in practical RL is to rely on **automatic differentiation** such as the one in pytorch, jax etc. The trick is that in RL we often derive explicit equation of **update** rather than loss. Consequently we need to create a **surrogate** function such that after automatic differentiation, it will create the update rule of interest.

Here the derivation is simple, just take a gradient of critic_loss wrt w and you will end up with the update rule from literature.

```
d/d_w critic_loss[w] = d/d_w 0.5 * (returns - v_hat(states, w))**2 
                     = (returns - v_hat(states, w)) * d/d_w (returns - v_hat(states, w))
                     = -(returns - v_hat(states, w)) * d/d_w v_hat(states, w)
```

Another way around it would be to instead implement **custom gradient** but it is often more messy in current libraries and thus - avoided.

Comment: So it seems that it comes down to manually pick a surrogate function that it's derivative equals the negative gradient of the objective function.
Indeed in this example it is easy to do so, but I wonder if that strategy holds up for more complicated update rules...

Comment: Also, are we allowed to derive the gradient like that, like we do for single variable derivatives? (pardon my mathematical ignorance)

Comment: gradient is just a vector of partial derivatives (what you call "single variable derivatives") so the math will end up being very similar. The strategy almost always works because of a hacky "stop gradient" mechanics that allows to wrap a function and zero-out its gradient. There are very exotic things that can't be solved this way but then you can always just write a custom gradient.